# Show that two denumerable models are isomorphic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, model-theory

Here’s a problem I’m struggling with:

Let M and N be two denumerable models for the theory of equivalence relations such that:

(i) Every equivalence class in M and N has infinitely many members

(ii) There are infinitely many distinct equivalence classes in both M and N

Show that M and N are isomorphic

I’m frankly not even sure how to start. My guess is that we must show that the set of equivalence relations is denumerably categorical, but I’m not sure how to do that

Comment: "The set of equivalence relations is denumerably categorical". This sentence doesn't make sense. Do you know what a model for the theory of equivalence relations is? Do you know what it means for such a model to be denumerable?

Comment: @AlexKruckman you’re right, it doesn’t make sense. A model for the theory of equivalence relations is a model that makes true reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. The denumerable model consists of a denumerable set with an equivalence relation in which all elements are in the same equivalence class. Is that right? If so, would the correct route then be to show the two models have the same signature?

Comment: "A model for the theory of equivalence relations is a model that makes true reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity." Correct. "The denumerable model consists of a denumerable set with an equivalence relation in which all elements are in the same equivalence class." In fact, there are many denumerable models - some have all elements in the same equivalence class, others do not. A denumerable model consists of a denumerable set with an equivalence relation. Period.

Comment: @AlexKruckman that makes sense, but one of the problems in our textbook says “Show that two denumerable models of Eq are isomorphic iff they have the same signature” which is why I asked if showing they have the same signature was sufficient

Comment: @AlexKruckman “Computability and Logic” by Boolos, 5th edition. Here’s the definition: We can also describe such a model by describing its signature, the infinite sequence of numbers whose 0th entry is the number (which may be 0, 1, 2, . . . , or infinite) of equivalence classes having infinitely many elements and whose nth entry for n > 0 is the number of equivalence classes with exactly n elements.

Comment: @Thomas Ah! I apologize. People often use the word "signature" as a synonym for "language" (set of constant, function, and relation symbols). Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey use the word "language". Here they're using the word "signature" to describe isomorphism invariants for equivalence relations. So yes, showing $M$ and $N$ have the same signature is indeed a good way to start! I'll delete my last few comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are two countable models with the properties (i) and (ii). (I will write countable instead of denumerable throughout this answer).

By (2), $M$ has infinitely many classes, and since $M$ is countable, it has countably infinitely many classes. So we can enumerate the classes $C_1, C_2, \dots$.

Similarly, $N$ has countably infinitely many classes, which we can enumerate $D_1, D_2, \dots$.

Each class $C_i$ in $M$ is infinite, and since $M$ is countable, it is countably infinite. So we can enumerate the elements of $C_i$ as $a^i_1, a^i_2,\dots$.

Similarly, we can enumerate the elements of each class $D_i$ as $b^i_1, b^i_2, \dots$.

Now let $f\colon M\to N$ be defined by $a^i_j\mapsto b^i_j$ for all $i,j\in \mathbb{N}$. I'll leave it to you to verify that this is an isomorphism $M\cong N$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this! Also, thank you for your feedback on the answer I posted!

Comment: @AndrewOstergaard No problem! No need to delete your answer. The back and forth method is definitely a more flexible way of showing isomorphisms between countable models, so I think it adds something to see how back-and-forth works out here. It just so happens that in this case, it's possible to write down an isomorphism more explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Appreciate all the help :)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thank you for your encouragement, and thank you for reading my stuff and giving valuable feedback. I'm going to take your suggestion, and undelete my answer. Unfortunately, I won't be able to incorporate the edits you suggested until later this evening. (I need to go home).

Answer (score 2):

Please note: Alex Kruckman has posted a much nicer answer. I considered deleting the following, but it was suggested that I leave it up. Alex, thanks for your help!

Let's let $E$ be the symbol for the equivalence relation.

One way to show the two models are isomorphic is to use what's called a back and forth argument. We want to build a sequence $M_0\subseteq M_1\subseteq M_2\subseteq\ldots$ of finite subsets of $M$, a sequence $N_0\subseteq N_1\subseteq N_2\subseteq\ldots$ of finite subsets of $N$, and a sequence $f_0,f_1,f_2,\ldots$ of functions such that for each $n\in\Bbb{N}$, $f_n:M_n\to N_n$ is an isomorphism. If we do this in a clever way, then $\underset{n\in\Bbb{N}}{\bigcup}f_n:M\to N$ will be an isomorphism.

Here's how to do it: we'll use the fact that $M=\{m_0,m_1,m_2,\ldots\}$ and $N=\{n_0,n_1,n_2,\ldots\}$, since $M$ and $N$ are countable. To start out, let $M_0=\{m_0\}$, let $N_0=\{n_0\}$, and let $f_0=\{(m_o,n_0)\}$.

Next we need to check to see if $n_1 E\,n_0$. If $n_1E\,n_0$, then let $a_1$ be the earliest element of $m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots$ with $a_1E\,m_0$. If $\,\lnot(n_1E\,n_0)$, then let $a_1$ be the earliest element of $m_1,m_2,m_3,\ldots$ with $\lnot(a_1E\,m_0)$. Then let $M_1=\{m_0,a_1\}$, let $N_1=\{n_0,n_1\}$, and let $f_1=\{(m_o,n_0),(a_1,n_1)\}$.

At this point, we've constructed $M_0\subseteq M_1$, $N_0\subseteq N_1$, and isomorphisms $f_0:M_0\to N_o$ and $f_1:M_1\to N_1$. Also, note that $f_0\subseteq f_1$.

Suppose that for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we've already constructed $M_0\subseteq\ldots\subseteq M_{2n+1}$, $N_0\subseteq\ldots\subseteq N_{2n+1}$, and isomorphisms $f_i:M_i\to N_i$ for $0\le i\le2n+1$, such that $f_0\subseteq\ldots\subseteq f_{2n+1}$. We'll use these to construct $f_{2n+2}$ and $f_{2n+3}$ as follows:

First, let $a_{2n+2}$ be the earliest element of the $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots\,$ such that $a_{2n+2}$ is not an element of $M_{2n+1}$. Let $M_{2n+2}=M_{2n+1}\cup\{a_{2n+2}\}$. Next, let $b_{2n+2}$ be the earliest element of $y_0,y_1,y_2\ldots$ such that $f_{2n+1}\cup\{(a_{2n+2},b_{2n+2})\}$ is an isomorphism. Note: the fact that we can find $b_{2n+2}$ follows from the fact that $M$ and $N$ have infinitely many equivalence classes, all of which are infinite. Let $N_{2n+2}=N_{2n+1}\cup\{b_{2n+2}\}$, and let $f_{2n+2}=f_{2n+1}\cup\{(a_{2n+2},b_{2n+2})\}$.

Now let $b_{2n+3}$ be the earliest element of the $y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots\,$ such that $b_{2n+3}$ is not an element of $N_{2n+2}$. Let $N_{2n+3}=N_{2n+2}\cup\{b_{2n+3}\}$. Next, let $a_{2n+3}$ be the earliest element of $x_0,x_1,x_2\ldots$ such that $f_{2n+2}\cup\{(a_{2n+3},b_{2n+3})\}$ is an isomorphism. Note: the fact that we can find $a_{2n+3}$ follows from the fact that $M$ and $N$ have infinitely many equivalence classes, all of which are infinite. Let $M_{2n+3}=M_{2n+2}\cup\{a_{2n+3}\}$, and let $f_{2n+3}=f_{2n+2}\cup\{(a_{2n+3},b_{2n+3})\}$.

Notice, that at odd stages, we're picking the first available element of $M$, and then picking an element of $N$ so that $f_{2k}$ is an isomorphism. At even stages, we're picking the first available element of $N$, and then picking an element of $M$ so that $f_{2k+1}$ is an isomorphism. This is how we know that $\underset{n\in\Bbb{N}}{\bigcup}M_i=M$ and $\underset{n\in\Bbb{N}}{\bigcup}N_i=N$. The fact that each $f_i:M_i\to N_i$ is an isomorphism and that $f_0\subseteq f_1\subseteq f_2\subseteq\ldots\,$ gives us that $\underset{n\in\Bbb{N}}{\bigcup}f_i:M\to N$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Looks good to me. I just have two comments: (1) it would be better to denote the equivalence relation by $E$ rather than $\cong$, since $\cong$ often denotes an isomorphism, and in a context where you're buildling an isomorphism, that's a bit confusing. (2) Yes, there is an easier way :0)

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks a lot for reading it! My LaTeX skills are not so great, so if I replace $\cong$ with $E$, I'm not sure what I'll do to replace $\ncong$. Do you have any suggestions? Also, would you be willing to post an easier solution? I would definitely upvote it!

Comment: Well, you could use $\not E$ (\not E), though it's not pretty. Or $\lnot (xEy)$ (\lnot x E y).